# Is there any way to integrate Bitbucket on cloud and Jenkins On premise

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, bitbucket, continuous-deployment

I am trying to integrate Bitbucket on cloud and Jenkins on premise, but once I enter the IP of my local Jenkins in Bitbucket cloud it show error URL not valid.

Is there a way to solve this, or do I need to buy Jenkins cloud license?

Comment: Are you trying to have a Bitbucket commit trigger Jenkins, or Jenkins look for commits and trigger itself?  The latter worked for me in the past (3+ years ago).

Comment: Bitbucket commit trigger Jenkins.Problem i am facing is my bitbucket is on cloud and Jenkins on my local machine, so it doesn't take the private ip for integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your local Jenkins server is not seen by a cloud Bitbucket server because it is an internal server.
You can solve it in one of those alternatives:

- Ask your system administrator to expose your Jenkins server with a global IP address along with the Jenkins port (e.g. 8080) so the Bitbucket server will be able to access it. This is not totally secure due.
- Activate the Jenkins job that pulls from the remote BitBucket server on time internal - in the Job 'Build Triggers' section check the 'Poll SCM' checkbox and set the cron setting (for example: 'H/15 * * * *' for building every 15 minutes. Notice that it will not build if there were no code changes)